# If Else Statement is giving an error that I'm missing an End If statement

Tags: if-statement, vbscript

I'm hoping for another set of eyes to look over my code. I'm writing a relatively big If...Else... statement. It appears that everything is coded properly. I've stepped through the entire script but one spot keeps giving me an `"Expected 'End If'"` When it seems to me that I don't need that.

Simply put, I'm trying to say: If blah, do these for things. Else If blah, only do one of those things.

Here's the block of code:

```
If(sLogFile <> "" AND nPing <> 1) Then
    pingStatus = 1

    If(findTag(sLogFile, daRunning) = 1) Then
        daStatus = 1
    Else If(findTag(sLogFile, daNotRunning) = 1) Then
        daStatus = 2
    Else
        daStatus = 3
    End If

    If(daStatus = 1 AND findTag(sLogFile, daDataFlowing) = 1) Then
        daFlowStatus = 1
    Else If(daStatus = 1 AND findTag(sLogFile, daDataNotFlowing) = 1) Then
        daFlowStatus = 2
    Else If(daStatus = 1 AND findTag(sLogFile, daDataUnchecked) = 1) Then
        daFlowStatus = 3
    Else If(daStatus <> 1) Then
        daFlowStatus = 4
    End If

    If(findTag(sLogFile, aeRunning) = 1) Then
        aeStatus = 1
    Else If(findTag(sLogFile, aeNotRunning) = 1) Then
        aeStatus = 2
    Else
        aeStatus = 3
    End If

    If(findTag(sLogFile, aeDataUnchecked) = 1) Then
        aeFlowStatus = 2
    Else If(findTag(sLogFile, aeDataExecutionError) = 1) Then
        aeFlowStatus = 3
    Else If(findTag(sLogFile, aeDataConnectionError) = 1) Then
        aeFlowStatus = 4
    Else If(findTag(sLogFile, aeTimeStamp) = 1) Then
        location = InStr(sLogFile, aeTimeStamp)
        leftTrimmedString = LTrim(Mid(sLogFile, (location - 2)))
        location = InstrRev(leftTrimmedString, ":")
        dateString = Trim(Mid(leftTrimmedString, 1, (location + 5)))
        timeDiff = DateDiff("h", dateString, Now)
        If(timeDiff > 5) Then
            aeFlowStatus = 5
        Else
            aeFlowStatus = 1
        End If
    End If

Else If(nPing = 1) Then
    pingStatus = 2

    If(findTag(sLogFile, aeDataUnchecked) = 1) Then
        aeFlowStatus = 2
    Else If(findTag(sLogFile, aeDataExecutionError) = 1) Then
        aeFlowStatus = 3
    Else If(findTag(sLogFile, aeDataConnectionError) = 1) Then
        aeFlowStatus = 4
    Else If(findTag(sLogFile, aeTimeStamp) = 1) Then
        location = InStr(sLogFile, aeTimeStamp)
        leftTrimmedString = LTrim(Mid(sLogFile, (location - 2)))
        location = InstrRev(leftTrimmedString, ":")
        dateString = Trim(Mid(leftTrimmedString, 1, (location + 5)))
        timeDiff = DateDiff("h", dateString, Now)
        If(timeDiff > 5) Then
            aeFlowStatus = 5
        Else
            aeFlowStatus = 1
        End If
    End If
End If
```

The error keeps happening at the main `Else If` about 2/3 of the way down (`Else If(nPing = 1) Then`). I'm getting the error on that line.

I've tried separating the block into two blocks by putting an `End If` above the Else IF, then changing the `Else If` to an `If`. It works when I do that but I don't really want two if statements.

So, did I mess up, or is there a problem with my interpreter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Basic the "else if" statement is written `ElseIf` not `Else If`. I think that's your problem.

Comment: `Else If` is valid syntax in VBScript, but it requires that the corresponding `End If` also appear within the Else block. In other words, the Else block encapsulates another If block.

Comment: @Nilpo that's a stretch isn't it? If you're talking about a nested `If` inside the `Else` block the actual `If` statement wouldn't start on the same line, hardly the same thing. Matthew is right the correct syntax is `ElseIf`.

Comment: @Lankymart Yes, that's what I'm talking about. The nested If does start on the same line, and it is valid syntax.

Comment: @Nilpo. It's a good point. It better explains why the "expected End If" error was occurring than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you should be using `ElseIf` not `Else If`.  See the difference?

Now, the bigger issue is that you will always have trouble figuring out errors with such a huge chunk of "spaghetti code".  Consider breaking your code up into small re-usable methods.  That way, you'll be able to figure out where the problem lies more-easily.  Not to mention the fact that it hurts to even look at all those `if` blocks all crammed together.

Comment: Ya, it was as terrible to write as it is to read - I don't usually write code like this. Sorry to make you have to read through it! Thanks for the help though.